# Can locust make n requests per user?

Tags: locust

How can I run a Locust load test with n number of users, where each user has a unique token that is used to make requests?

```
headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token
        }
response = self.client.put(f"/api/{id}/like", headers=headers)
```

I want to make one request from each user, but they need to be in one moment. I want to test if my database and service can handle n number of users in one moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
list_of_tokens = …

class MyUser(…):
    def on_start(self):
        self.token = list_of_tokens.pop()

    @task
    def t(self)
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ self.token
        }
        response = self.client.put(f"/api/{id}/like", headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i think you are not understood me correctly.
User in my case are not locust users. Users that can login with token.
user1 -> token1 -> request1
user2 -> token2 -> request2
user3 -> token3 -> request3
and this whole request would need to be done in one second.
When run locust with this command `locust -f main.py --users 10`, it will run 10 requests for each request, so total would be 30 requests